# SSRS drop down parameter values not set as defined

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a simple SSRS report, on which I have a parameter called year and it is a drop down of many years. I defined the parameter as a list of specified values. I defined both the label and the value of the drop down to be the year number. You can see it in the picture below. But after I deployed it, the values of drop down list are 1,2,3,4,5,6..., which are not my year numbers! I am puzzled.

I cleaned the solution, rebuilt the solution, re-deployed the solution, the problem remains.

This is Sql server 2012 express reporting service.

I don't know why. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: There's no picture?  Can you also provide a screenshot of the list of specified values?

Comment: Did you originally use values 1 - 7?

Comment: @trubs: The attached picture has 2 screen shots. The one on the left tells you my specified values, the one on the right tells you the actual values that are rendered and spitted out to HTML.

Comment: @Ewan: No, I never used values 1 through 7.

Comment: In an attempt to check if it is a cache issue, I just created a different report with a drop down parameter of years. The strange thing is: In the SSRS report authoring tool (SQL Server Data Tool), the report pulls out data correctly on the Preview tab. But once I deploy it, the drop down values are altered to cardinals, which causes the report to stop working. This sounds to me like a bug. Somehow the Report.aspx page or child controls thereof are regenerating the drop down values and discarding user defined values.

Comment: I've found that this is the intended behavior, and it works in IE, but not in Chrome or FireFox. It still puzzles me. Where is the real drop down values stored such that it works in IE?

Comment: Yes, well... Seemingly expected behaviour.  Strange more people have not come across this (or found it a problem)?

but anyway - while this is easily re-creatable, how does this issue manifest as a problem for your report?   SSRS obviously retains the values and its easy enough to display the Value and Label in your report as well as passing values as parameters to datasets...?

Comment: Yes, apparently, not many people have found this to be a problem. SSRS does seem to only work well (not all the time of course) in IE. That's a problem. In my situation, I have a requirement to add a button to the Report.aspx page using javascript and upon clicking the button, I need to get the values of the parameters and redirect users to another application. I guess I will just read the text labels and work with those instead of the underline values. Not ideal, but where are the real values of my drop downs? How and where does ssrs service get such values?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this creating a report using VS2012 and publishing to SSRS 2014 server where it works correctly in chrome.

I found the same using SSRS 2008R2 report server in Chrome

A workaround would be to use a dataset to supply your parameter values instead of having fixed parameter values.

Drop down values are stored in the report xml if you use fixed values